# How to get only text instead of list item from form_errors

Tags: forms, text, twig, message, symfony-4.4

I'm trying to display an error message for a repeated password field in Symfony 4.4.

Here is the relevant code in the form class file:

```
->add('password', RepeatedType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'invalid_message' => 'Le mot de passe et sa confirmation ne sont pas identiques',
            'type' => PasswordType::class,
            'first_options' => array('label' => false,'error_bubbling' => true),
            'second_options' => array('label' => false),
        ))
```

And here is my relevant twig/HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4 mb-4">
                                    <div class="form-outline">
                                        {{ form_row(registrationForm.password.first ,{'label':false,'attr':{'placeholder':'Mot de passe', 'name':'password1', 'class':'form-control', 'id':'password1'} } ) }}
                                        <span style="color: red">{{ form_errors(registrationForm.password|first) }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Actually, if I change `form_errors(registrationForm.password|first)` to `form_errors(registrationForm.password)`, I get this:

[image]

However, that is not the wanted result since I need to display only a simple text, and I really wonder why `form_errors(registrationForm.password|first)` didn't work for me. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it! I've actually followed a different approach. In my HTML\Twig code, I've changed this line `<span style="color: red">{{ form_errors(registrationForm.password|first) }}</span>` like so:

`<span class="Errormessage" style="color: red;text-align: right">{{ form_errors(registrationForm.password) }}</span>`

Then, I added the code below in my CSS code:

```
.Errormessage li {
    list-style-type: none !important;
}
```